# Singleton redux store for Angular Electron app

Tags: angular, redux, electron

So I have an Electron app that holding an Angular SPA. The state of the app is handled using ngrx Redux.

I'm looking to be able to create a new `BrowserWindow` and have the state from the original window persisted. I've seen with React this can be done using [`redux-electron-store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-electron-store) but I can't seem to find anything similar for Angular. Is this possible with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ipc.

**Original window render JS**

```
    import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";

    let personName = 'Leandro'
    let personAge = -1

    ipcRenderer.send("send-data", {name:personName, age:personAge})
```

**Main/index.js**

```
    // When receives data from ipcRenderer/Original renderer 
    // emits that data to channel "here is your data"
    ipcMain.on("send-data", function(event, args){
        ipcMain.emit("here-isyour-data", data) 
    })
```

**Receiver renderer**

```
    let personName = null
    let personAge = null
    ipcRenderer.on("here-isyour-data",function(event, args) {
       personName = args.personName
       personAge = args.personAge
    })
```

Its better to make the main index.js the controller, but if you want you can make the renderer process comunicate with each other using `ipcRenderer.sendTo()`.

**To solve your problem you could do this**

```
// On creation/indexjs
let newWindow = new BrowserWindow()
 newWindow.emit('hey, im created')

 // On render.js
 let personName = null
 let personAge = null
 newWindow.once('oke, here is your data', function(event, args){
       personName = args.personName
       personAge = args.personAge
})

// On original render.js

    let personName = 'Leandro'
    let personAge = -1
    ipcRenderer.once("hey, im created", function(){
       ipcRenderer.send("oke, here is your data", {name:personName, age:personAge})
    })
```

**OR**

Have mainRenderer as middle man on "// On creation/indexjs".

I hope that I've helped, I never used angular, but I think you're able to achieve this using electron.

For more information visit electron: [ipc Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)

If you want a cool and improving window handler go here: [GitHub](https://github.com/leandrojesus-programmer/electron-window-handler)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this lib [elctron-ngrx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-ngrx)